# XSLT remove leading characters, underscore and trailing characters

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an element that is populated with a value which always follows this format:

- 6 Characters (Alphanumeric)
- Underscore
- 8 digits
- Underscore 6 digits
- Variable (Sometimes nothing other time another underscore followed but a string of one to 5
  characters long.

Some examples:

```
<ID>MBAA01_20151014_103605_H3Y</ID>
<ID>34FG01_22251123_341234</ID>
<ID>F6F7G8_30151124_279321_YU</ID>
<ID>123SDT_45891212_345321</ID>
```

I am trying to write an XSLT that will:

- Remove the first 7 characters (the 6 and the underscore)
- Remove the underscore between the set of 8 digits and 6 digits
- Remove any characters, if there are, that follow the set of 6 digits.

So the examples above would look like this after being transformed:

```
<ID>20151014103605</ID>
<ID>22251123341234</ID>
<ID>30151124279321</ID>
<ID>45891212345321</ID>
```

The actual original source XML would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FeedbackAssets>
            <ID>MBAA01_20151014_103605_H3Y</ID>
            <PlanNumber1>A01</PlanNumber1>
            <PlanNumber2>B02</PlanNumber2>
            <PlanNumber3>CA03</PlanNumber3>
            <PlanNumber4>D04</PlanNumber4>
            <PlanNumber5>F5</PlanNumber5>
</FeedbackAssets>
<FeedbackAssets>
            <ID>34FG01_20151123_341234</ID>
            <PlanNumber1>MM4</PlanNumber1>
            <PlanNumber2>11</PlanNumber2>
            <PlanNumber3>CA03</PlanNumber3>
            <PlanNumber4>D6</PlanNumber4>
            <PlanNumber5>Y5</PlanNumber5>
</FeedbackAssets>
<FeedbackAssets>
            <ID>F6F7G8_20151124_279321_YU</ID>
            <PlanNumber1>ZZ5</PlanNumber1>
            <PlanNumber2>B02</PlanNumber2>
            <PlanNumber3>CA03</PlanNumber3>
            <PlanNumber4>D04</PlanNumber4>
            <PlanNumber5>FR5</PlanNumber5>
</FeedbackAssets>
<FeedbackAssets>
            <ID>123SDT_20151212_345321</ID>
            <PlanNumber1>WE4</PlanNumber1>
            <PlanNumber2>G6H</PlanNumber2>
            <PlanNumber3>CA03</PlanNumber3>
            <PlanNumber4>D04</PlanNumber4>
            <PlanNumber5>G5</PlanNumber5>
</FeedbackAssets>
```

Thank you

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to write an XSLT that will:
>
> - Remove the first 7 characters (the 6 and the underscore)
> - Remove the underscore between the set of 8 digits and 6 digits
> - Remove any characters, if there are, that follow the set of 6 digits.

This could be restated as:

- Remove all underscores;
- Skip the first 6 characters and return the next 14 characters.

Assuming a template matching `ID` this comes down to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(translate( ., '_', ''), 7, 14)" />
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks again! You helped me out last week as well. That work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

With **XSL-T 2.0** you can use regular expression-based replacements:

```
<xsl:template match="ID">
   <ID>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(./text(), '[A-Z0-9]{6}_(\d{8})_(\d{6})(_[A-Z0-9]{1,5})?', '$1$2')"/>
   </ID>
</xsl:template>
```